# jQuery | Autocomplete input field fails to display autocompleted value

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete

please check this JSFiddle at first: http://goo.gl/WiY827

After selecting it should display the complete address. Unfortunately this does not happen. Instead there are just the typed in letters shown.

I would really appreciate your help!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation there is a event for when a result is inserted into the form called `geocode:result` you need to add that to your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/EcPdP/14/

```
$("#input-geo").geocomplete().bind("click", function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}).on("geocode:result", function(event, result){
    $('#message').html('Your Location:  ' + $('#input-geo').val());
});
```

Comment: @user3439585 if the answer is correct please accept it to help anyone else with the same question that finds this post.